# How do I get the current route's or(upcoming route's) data?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have data in my routes and I want to get it in the guard. I have tried a tutorial that used ActivatedRouteSnapshot, I was getting the following errror.

Error: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!

Here is my routes.ts:

```
import { LayoutComponent } from '../layout/layout.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../core/auth/auth-guard.service';
export const routes = [

    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate:[AuthGuard], data:{permission:'users.create'} },
            { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule',canActivate:[AuthGuard],data:{permission:'users.create'} }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    // Not found
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }

];
```

And my auth-guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) {}
    canActivate(){
        if(!this.authService.loggedIn()){
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }else{
            if(this.route.data['permission']){
                if(!this.authService.hasAccess(this.route.data['permission'])){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `ActivatedStateSnapshot` and a `RouterStateSnapshot` are passed as parameters to `CanActivate`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   ...
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: Golly jeeze! I was passing it into the construct.